# Directory select with Zenity

Tags: bash, zenity

How to use zenity to only allow the user to select certain directory.

my code works file to filter out certain files types

```
zenity --title "Pick The Software Folder " --file-selection  --file-  filter=""*.zip" "*.sql" "*.tgz"" --directory
```

I would like the code to only allow the user to be able to select certain directory's

```
 zenity --title "Pick The Software Folder " --file-selection  --file-  filter=""Download" "Home" "Desktop"" --directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
zenity  --file-selection --title="Choose a directory" --file-filter=""Downloads" "Desktop"" --directory
```

[image]

Comment: The double-double quotes are unnecessary and may be misleading.  "Downloads Desktop" is probably more clear.  As far as I can tell there's no way to properly escape white-space with zenity, and so you must limit yourself to glob patterns without spacing.